# Starting remote Erlang nodes

Tags: erlang, distributed-computing, erlang-otp, master-slave

I want to write a master-slave application in Erlang. I am thinking at the following things I need from the architecture:

- the slaves shouldn't die when the master dies, but rather try to reconnect to it while the master is down
- the master should automatically start the remote nodes if they don't connect automatically or they are down (probably the supervisor behaviour in [OTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Telecom_Platform))

Is there a OTP oriented behaviour to do this? I know I can start remote nodes with `slave:start_link()` and I can monitor nodes with `erlang:monitor()`, but I don't know how this can be incorporated in a `gen_server` behaviour.

Comment: The functions erlang:monitor_node/2 and erlang:monitor_node/3 are also available.

Comment: Did you see the distributed applications section? http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/distributed_applications.html

Comment: We need some clear terminology here. Do you want to distribute your application over multiple erlang VMs (that is run multiple node()'s) or do you want to build a fault tolerant tree of processes? It is not entirely clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments about using erlang:monitor_node and the use of distributed applications.

You cannot just use the slave module to accomplish that, it clearly states "All slave nodes which are started by a master will terminate automatically when the master terminates".

There is currently no OTP behaviour to do it either.  Supervision trees are hierarchical ; it seems like you are looking for something where there is a hierarchy in terms of application logic, but spawning is done an a peer-to-peer basis (or an individual basis, depending upon your point of view).

If you were to use multiple Erlang VMs then you should carefully consider how many you run, as a large number of them may cause performance issues due to the OS swapping OS processes in and out.  A rule of thumb for best performance is to aim for having no more than one OS process (i.e. one Erlang VM) per CPU core.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in studying other implementations, Basho's [riak_core](https://github.com/basho/riak_core) framework has a pretty good take on decentralized distributed applications.

[riak_core_node_watcher.erl](https://github.com/basho/riak_core/blob/master/src/riak_core_node_watcher.erl) has most of the interesting node observation code in it.

Search and you'll find there are quite a few [talks and presentations about the framework](http://www.bing.com/search?q=riak+core+erlang).